# Checking if the input value fits some condition when entering a list in Python

Tags: python, list

is there any way to check if the inputted value is less than some variable value and put it in the list only then? it should be as fast as it may be, so I cannot check values in the list after inputting it and then removing invalid ones.

```
n = int(input())
list_of_participants = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do that:

```
list_of_participants = [x for x in map(int, input().split()) if x < limit]
```

or:

```
list_of_participants = list(filter(lambda x: x < limit, map(int, input().split())))
```

(Asssuming that the variable `limit` contains the maximum value + 1 for the list elements.)